# lowercase and uppercase file name

Tags: php, codeigniter, camelcasing

I used codeigniter framework on my localhost, i named some of my models and controllers using the camel case method(UserModel,DbModel) on windows.Now when i uploaded the files to the server(running on linux) the script is trying to load all the files with all lowercase so i get 404 errors because the script is looking for usermodel not UserModel, any way to go around this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to the 'pissed by crippled `spl_autoload()` implementation' club.

You basically can either

1.Rename all your files to lowercase

or

2.Write/find an autoloader that looks for proper filenames. [Here's Symofony's ClassLoader Component](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/class_loader.html) which works great.

Comment: My guess the php `spl_autoload()` implementors won't change this to prevent breaking enything. Anyway class names in PHP are not case sensitive anyway. [(pretty much everything else is](https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/php-syntax/)

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't store file names with case sensitivity.  You'll need to either rename your files on the linux machine, or force all of your file references to lower case.

Comment: Windows (I'm assuming we don't talk about pre XP editions here :P ) does store filenames with proper case. It just doesn't care what case it is, when it looks the file up. So you can save the file as `CamelCase.ext` but if you look up for `CAMELcase.ExT` you will find it.

Comment: Have fun renaming them, you could do a simple script in VBS for your windows machine to rename all the files in a specific directory, calling LOWERCASE(filename). Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Linux file names are case sensitive unlike windows. So you must be explicit in what you call. Change the script to use the Pascal Case method you are showing above and it will function correctly.

Alternatively set a redirect in your web-server, to look for the Pascal Case version of the file.

What language are you using and what web server?

Comment: I'm using php server is x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu